# Cannot open powerpoint presentation pps or ppsm file in powerpoint 2013

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I am having trouble since upgrading from office 2010 to 2013. In particular with regards to PowerPoint. I have a requirement to open a presentation show file .pps or .ppsm which used to open fine in office 2010 using the following code

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1

    Sub main()

        Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
        Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim file As String

        file = "C:myfile.ppsm" 'example file/location'

        pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        pptApp.Visible = True
        pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(file)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Since upgrading to to Office 2013 the presentation show file now opens the file in desktop mode.

I have tried various trust settings without any success. Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: `file = "C:myfile.ppsm"` --> `file = "C:\myfile.ppsm"`

Comment: You are correct. The location / file is actually on a server. "C:myfile.ppsm" should have read "C:\myfile.ppsm"

Answer (score -1):

As a possible workaround you could convert .pps into .
pptx using a 3rd party service such as https://cloudconvert.com/api

Comment: As I stated on your more recent post: Posting links to 3rd-party services isn't an answer. It's advertising/spam.